# Structuring function definitions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, scope

I currently have some code like this:

```
def print_to_window(text):
    window.print_text(text)
    do_other_stuff()

class WithMethodsThatCallprint_to_window:
    something()

class ThatAlsoHasMethodsThatCallprint_to_window:
    something()


# actual game code starts  
window = Window()
a = WithMethodsThatCallprint_to_window()
while True:
    get_input()
    do_stuff()
```

Calling `Window` opens the window, which I don't want to happen when I import the module for testing.

I'd like to restructure this to have the "actual game code" in a `main` function, and then do `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`. However, I can't work out how to do this.

If I just move the code after `#actual game code starts` into a function, then `window` is no longer a global variable, and `print_to_window` can't access it.

However, moving `print_to_window` into the `main` function causes the same problem with the classes that use it.

How should I restructure the code?

Comment: This pseudocode is not useful, especially because you're calling `something()` at *class* level inside those two classes. Is that really what you're doing? Or do you mean `def something(self):` there?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, the `something` is just to fill the class body.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the name `window` at the global level, then assign it to an object in the main function:

```
window = None

def main():
    global window
    window = Window()
    # do things
    print_to_window("some text")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: forgot the "`global window`" in `main`, allowing `print_to_window` to see the modified `window`.